# Pivot icons are not clickable

Tags: html, css, ms-office

I have a **pivot element** in my page, it's work but when I want to change text by icons, they become not clickable and we have to click in the grey part. Do you know how make them clickable ?

[image]
In green the clickable part and in red not clickable part.

Part of my code :

```
<li id="listPivotAccount" class="ms-Pivot-link is-selected " data-content="account" title="Mon compte" tabindex="1">
   <i style="" class=" ms-Icon ms-Icon--Accounts" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</li>
```

[You can check the code here](https://jsfiddle.net/s63jno0m/8/)

Comment: It's better if you can add HTML and CSS code here

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle demo of your issue?

Comment: Sure, look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/s63jno0m/4/

Comment: Why is this tagged `ms-office`?

Comment: Because this is ms-office lib ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, I have never used SharePoint, so there may be a more elegant solution.

You can fix this behaviour by adding this vanilla JavaScript after your current JavaScript:

```
    // select all icons
    var msIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-Icon");

    // loop all icons
    for (var i = 0; i < msIcons.length; i++) {

        // add a click event to the nearest element with class "ms-Pivot-link"
        msIcons[i].closest(".ms-Pivot-link").addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.click();
        });
    }
```

jQuery Example of the above code:

```
    $(".ms-Icon").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest(".ms-Pivot-link").click();
    });
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, it's work fine. Thank's !

Comment: I just simplify the code :

`$('.ms-Icon').click(function() {
            this.closest(".ms-Pivot-link").addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.click();
            });
        });`

Surprisingly, this work in chrome but not in IE.

Comment: Well done! I didn't know you had access to jQuery. I've added my example of this solution with jQuery above. It will work with IE also.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry i didn't precise this... It's work with chrome and Edge 17 but not in IE 11. So i'm trying to run the code with attachEvent

Comment: Strange, this works fine in IE11 for me! Are you sure replaced the entire old JavaScript attempt with the jQuery one? I think it may be something else affecting it.

Comment: Yes, you can check the new here : https://jsfiddle.net/s63jno0m/26/
On every browser it's work nice but not in InternetExplorer 11

Comment: Code execution stop at "OnClick" step

Comment: Here's my working updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s63jno0m/31/ ... Please be aware that JSFiddle doesn't support IE! Make sure you are running this code from somewhere else if testing in IE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178612/discussion-between-gary-thomas-and-ebillis).

Answer (score 2):

```
var Dropdown = new Class({
    initialize: function() {
        var e = this;
        document.addEvents({
            "click:relay(.windowLabel, .dropdown a.dropdownTrigger)": function(t, n) {
                t && (t.preventDefault(),
                t.stopPropagation()), // issue is here
                e.showPopover.call(e, n)
            }
        }),
        document.body.addEventListener("click", function(t) {
            e.hideOutside.call(e, t)
        })
    },
    // ...
})
```

Problem is in **preventing propagation of events**, and as result all nested elements shouldn't emit what you need.

*What is the solution?*
You can try add the icon in different way (for example using `:before`, `:after`)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to fix it is to trigger the pivot with a click. So if you use JQuery :

```
$('.ms-Icon').click(function () {
            var pivot = $(this).closest(".ms-Pivot-link");
            pivot.click();
        });
```

Short and compatible with IE > 9